# How to drop a test database after the unit-test in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a Visual Studio unit-test that creates a database for testing purposes, but the test database is not dropped after the test. What do I have to do to drop the test database after the unit-test successfully ran through?

Answer (score 0):

You could just issue a "DROP DATABASE..." command at your teardown method...